# How do I have a usercontrol add a Html String to Head of a MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I know this is easy when you know what you are adding. For example, with a UI control its

Page.Header.Controls.Add([control])

However, I am pulling HTML code from a CMS database. In other words, I need to add a string to the Head section of the master page.

Comment: I prefer to use jQuery and add the HTML to a div

Comment: It is in the head section. Jquery might not be an option - depending on if my users want it or not on sites.

Comment: Do you use VB.NET or C#?

Comment: i think you have parse your html code and make a runtime object and add to masterpage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `Literal` control to the Header by using code similar to the one you show in your question:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lit = new LiteralControl();
        lit.Text = "<link href=\"test.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />";
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(lit);
    }
}
```

Comment: You know, I never even thought of that! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a master page, you could:

Master page markup:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MyHeadContentPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
</html>
```

Content page markup:

```
<asp:Content ID="MyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MyHeadContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
<asp:Literal ID="MyLiteralForCmsContent" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</asp:Content>
```

Content page code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //Load the literal with content from the CMS.
        this.MyLiteralForCmsContent.Text = ""; //Hook up the call to the CMS here.
    }
}
```